# If/Else Statement on character strings from SPIM system calls

Tags: mips, spim

I'm writing a program in MIPS using Spim and I want to convert temperatures to/from fahrenheit and celsius.  For example:

```
Enter a number to convert: 100
Enter the Temperature: C
100 C is the same as 212 F
```

So I'm having trouble getting the program to recognize if the user input a "C" or an "F" and jump to the appropriate label.  Here's the part of the code I'm having trouble with:

```
li $v0, 8           # Loads System service to read string
syscall
move $s1, $v0        # Move value to register to save for later use

beq $s1, 'C', Fahrenheit
beq $s1, 'F', Celsius
```

The program just passes by the 'beq' lines without doing anything.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: The read-character system call is `$v0=12` https://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/MARS/Help/SyscallHelp.html.  You could have used that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike reading integers, reading strings does not read the user input into register `$v0`. A register in MIPS is only 4 bytes, so it doesn't make sense to store a string in a single register. Instead, MIPS will read it into memory starting at a specified address.

The read string syscall in MIPS works like this:

- `$a0` is the start address of the buffer in memory where the string is to be kept (you don't need to choose this yourself--you just allocate the space with a label name and MIPS will choose an address for you)
- `$a1` is the length of the string buffer in bytes. **For a single character you want this to be 2**, because strings use their last byte as a null-terminator. If this is 1, the syscall won't even read anything from the user since that character automatically needs to be a null-terminator.

You can allocate 2 bytes of memory for the string by including this in your `.data` section

```
myString:
    .space 2
```

Then perform the syscall in your `.text` section:

```
li $v0, 8
la $a0, myString   # myString is a label for the memory address
la $a1, 2
syscall
```

Then read the character (a single byte) you want into a register using `lb`

```
lb $s1, ($a0)
```

Your `beq` instruction should work as you expect now.

Comment: Sweet!  Thank you so much for helping me out and explaining everything so clearly!

Comment: @Kyle2595 Glad you found it helpful. :)

Comment: @Kyle2595 This is a good MIPS tutorial which also explains syscalls, if you're looking for one. http://logos.cs.uic.edu/366/notes/mips%20quick%20tutorial.htm